# When quitting one application, quit additional ones

Tags: mac, macos

I'm trying to figure out a way to do the following: when I quit Logic Pro X, I want to also automatically quit other apps that I use with it, as they are no longer needed. Is this possible?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868836/is-it-possible-to-write-an-applescript-so-that-when-i-close-one-program-it-also    There is also an update on my blog. http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/applescript-quit-or-launch-application-script-revised/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple Applescript to quit the other apps. To do it, open Script Editor and type the following:

```
tell application "AppName1" to quit
tell application "AppName2" to quit
tell application "AppName3" to quit
```

Save as Application.

Then when you quit Logic Pro, you just need to double click on your new app, and it close all your defined programs.

Comment: Oh, I'm absolutely new to this, could you please expand on your answer, how would I start the script on logic pro x quit? How do I create one and where would I save it? etc..

Comment: Ok, updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, but is there a way to launch this script when I quit logic pro, so I don't need to quit click it every time?

Comment: The idea is that you run this script _instead of_ quitting Logic Pro. (Logic Pro would be one of the apps being quit.) Save the script in `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Logic Pro`, and enable the `Script` menu. (You do that in `Script Editor→Preferences→General→Show Script menu in menu bar`.) To quit Logic Pro, choose this script from the Script menu _instead of_ choosing `Quit`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using [KeyboardMaestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com).